# FluentValidation Chain Properties Validation Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, chaining, fluentvalidation

I've just implemented INotifyDataErrorInfo using [JeremySkinner's FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation). However I have some difficulties with validation  of complex properties.

For example, I would like to validate Nationality property:

```
RuleFor(vm => vm.Nationality.SelectedItem.Value)
  .NotEmpty()
  .Length(0, 255);
```

However, this great looking peace of code has two major problems:

1) it throws null reference exception when SelectedItem is null.

it would be great if I could write something like this:

```
CustomizedRuleFor(vm => vm.Nationality.SelectedItem.Value)
   .NotEmpty(); //add some stuff here
```

2) full property path in error message, e.g: "The specified condition was not met for `'Nationality. Selected Item. Value'`". I only need `'Nationality'` in error message.

I know I can override error message using WithMessage extension method, but don't want to do it for every validation rule.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: you can write your own extenssion method for null checks and use it only for ths property

Comment: you mean `RuleFor(vm => vm.Nationality.SelectedItem.Value)`.CustomNotEmpty()? that does not work. Or you mean `RuleFor(vm => vm.Nationality).CustomNotEmpty()`? that does work, but I would have to write custom extension method for all validators (not empty, length, regex, etc) and all types of complex properties. That would be contraproductive

Comment: In which context you use FluentValidation: asp.net-mvc X, WPF, etc.?

Comment: WPF, I have implemented INotifyDataErrorInfo using FluentValidation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1.**

You can solve getting `NullReferenceException` problem by two ways, which depends on necessarity of client validation support and availablity to change model class:

Modify your model's default constructor to create `SelectedItem` with null value:

```
public class Nationality
{
    public Nationality()
    {
        // use proper class instead of SelectableItem 
        SelectedItem = new SelectableItem { Value = null };
    }
}
```

**Or** you can use conditional validation instead, if SelectedItem should be null in different cases and it's normal situation for you:

```
RuleFor(vm => vm.Nationality.SelectedItem.Value)
    .When(vm => vm.Nationality.SelectedItem != null)
    .NotEmpty()
    .Length(0, 255);
```

In this case validator will validate only when condition is true, but conditional validation doesn't support client-side validation (if you want to integrate with ASP.NET MVC).

**Problem 2.**

To save default error message format, add `WithName` method to rule builder method chain:

```
RuleFor(vm => vm.Nationality.SelectedItem.Value)
    .WithName("Nationality") // replace "Nationality.SelectedItem.Value" string with "Nationality" in error messages for both rules
    .NotEmpty()
    .Length(0, 255);
```

**UPDATE: GENERIC SOLUTION**

Extension method for rule builder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.Attributes;
using FluentValidation.Internal;


public static class FluentValidationExtensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<TModel, TProperty> ApplyChainValidation<TModel, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilderOptions<TModel, TProperty> builder, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expr)
    {
        // with name string
        var firstMember = PropertyChain.FromExpression(expr).ToString().Split('.')[0]; // PropertyChain is internal FluentValidation class

        // create stack to collect model properties from property chain since parents to childs to check for null in appropriate order
        var reversedExpressions = new Stack<Expression>();

        var getMemberExp = new Func<Expression, MemberExpression>(toUnwrap =>
        {
            if (toUnwrap is UnaryExpression)
            {
                return ((UnaryExpression)toUnwrap).Operand as MemberExpression;
            }

            return toUnwrap as MemberExpression;
        }); // lambda from PropertyChain implementation

        var memberExp = getMemberExp(expr.Body);
        var firstSkipped = false;

        // check only parents of property to validate
        while (memberExp != null)
        {
            if (firstSkipped)
            {
                reversedExpressions.Push(memberExp); // don't check target property for null
            }
            firstSkipped = true;
            memberExp = getMemberExp(memberExp.Expression);
        }

        // build expression that check parent properties for null
        var currentExpr = reversedExpressions.Pop();
        var whenExpr = Expression.NotEqual(currentExpr, Expression.Constant(null));
        while (reversedExpressions.Count > 0)
        {
            whenExpr = Expression.AndAlso(whenExpr, Expression.NotEqual(currentExpr, Expression.Constant(null)));
            currentExpr = reversedExpressions.Pop();
        }

        var parameter = expr.Parameters.First();
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(whenExpr, parameter); // use parameter of source expression
        var compiled = lambda.Compile();

        return builder
          .WithName(firstMember)
          .When(model => compiled.Invoke(model));
    }
}
```

And usage

```
RuleFor(vm => vm.Nationality.SelectedItem.Value)
  .NotEmpty()
  .Length(0, 255)
  .ApplyChainValidation(vm => vm.Nationality.SelectedItem.Value);
```

There is no possibility to escape redundant expression duplication, because `When()` method, which used inside extension method, *works for previously defined rules only*.

**Note: solution work for chains with reference types only.**

Comment: Thanks Evgeny. The When and WithName solutions is exactly what I have so far, but I was trying to get generic solution for that. I will try to create custom RuleFor method, that includes WithName and When operators automatically.